# Pandoc: Metadata

Tags: pdf, metadata, pandoc

I'm trying to convert a simple HTML file to a PDF, with some metadata inserted.

The command I'm using is

```
pandoc test.html -o test.pdf --metadata author:testtesttest
```

Contents of test.html

```
<p>Hello <em>pandoc</em>!</p>
<b>author: $author$</b>
```

However, the author tag is not replaced by `testtesttest` in the PDF that's generated. I'm assuming I'm missing something but after a Googling I'm at a loss.

Comment: This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38540135/) might be helpful.